JWT flow give {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved this consumer"} for scratch org
I have a test connected app setup in my scratch org with api, refresh_token and required scope enabled. I also added admin approved profiles and permission set to the connected app.
I have three users in my org, two build in users one with sys admin profile(adminUser) and one with integration profile(IntgUser), and one newly created user with Salesforce Standard profile(StandardUser).
using JWT flow, and login with server.key, I can successfully authenticate all user users into the org via the connected by running sf command
sf org login jwt --client-id=<cliendId> --jwt-key-file server.key --username=<username> --instance-url <orginstanceurl> --alias <myAlias> --json 

result:
Successfully authorized <username >with org ID [orgid]

However, when I try to authenticate in my Java code via /services/oauth2/token I get success response and accesstoken for AdminUser and IntgUser [scratch org build in user]. But I am getting below error for the new user "StandUser"

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"user hasn't approved
this consumer"}

What puzzled me was that why I could use jwt flow from salesforceCLI to authenticate standUser giving same privateKey but not able to do that via the code???
